# calculate goodness of fit matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution, chi-squared

I have a set of observations `obs`.

If I plot the histogram of the observation I see that they could come from a gamma distribution

```
[counts,x] = hist(obs,[1:max(obs)]);
```

I would like to prove it using chi square goodness of fit.

So I first estimate the gamma parameters

```
paramEsts = fitdist(obs,'Gamma');
```

and the use chi2gof to see if the hypotesis is true (h=0).

```
[h,p] = chi2gof(obs,'CDF',paramEsts)
```

My problem is that I get a p = NaN...how is it possible?
Where is my mistake?
Thanks

to test it please download the obs.mat file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3vXKJ_zYaCJbHU2SHhac29MRms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Works fine for me, `p=0.0212...`. Try doing `clear all` and running the code again.

Comment: Hi just realize that I posted a wrong vector for the observations

Comment: you can test it with this data 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3vXKJ_zYaCJbHU2SHhac29MRms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: From the documentation: "If there are not enough degrees of freedom to carry out the test, P is NaN."

Comment: @David thanks...Why there are not enough degrees of freedom?

Comment: Because statistics. I don't really know, that's something to look up with Google or on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have more or less the same problem with my set of data, @gabboshow did you find an answer?